# Multiple viewports onto the same JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, viewport, jtextarea

There is a component I would like to make which shows all matches of a set of words in a JTextArea, along with some context (N lines, probably user-configurable.)

I already have the code for highlighting the matches so I know their offsets and can therefore determine their bounds.  I know the line height of the text so I can determine the bounds of the context areas I want to paint.

But is there some class like JViewport only able to paint multiple views of the underlying component?  Since JViewport is a normal Swing component, as soon as you put the same text area under another viewport, it gets detached from the first one.

*Edit:* Actually as it turns out, I can't seem to determine the bounds of the context areas as the lines-to-offset mapping JTextArea gives me doesn't count wrapped lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that JViewport is a normal container, and treats its view component as a child component (and each component can only be child in one container). This is quite reasonable, given that always only one component can have the focus, and similar things.

I don't know of any JViewport-like class that would do what you want (painting a view of a component without being parent of it), but in your case, you can achieve most of the same by using two JTextAreas sharing the same Document. You then only would have to synchronize the caret movements (if so wished), I think.

Comment: I tried to write such a viewport which keeps a mapping of view rectangle to text rectangle and back.  This renders correctly but now of course events won't work.  So it seems like the JTextArea does have to be present in the component hierarchy, but somehow I need to make different bits of it translate differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that exists as you describe.  In fact it sounds like you want to customize the display of a JTextArea.  In which case you can override and change the way JTextArea paints itself.  Either painting more on top, or changing it completely.

Comment: It's dramatically different from the way JTextArea paints itself, because JTextArea paints all the text but my component would only paint around the parts which have a Highlight on them.  At the moment I am fighting with this, and can get it to paint correctly but of course mouse input is the next problem.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are doing but you could let the JTextArea paint everything and you could just paint the highlighted part or over the areas that JTextArea paints, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Paint your JTextArea in an Image and use necessary fragments of the image. Keep the image's bounds in original JTextArea so clicking bu the image you can calculate click on the JTextArea to get proper position.